# shade section of bin in histogram in r

Tags: r, plot, formatting, histogram

I have a histogram that plots the values in `data` in bins of 5. The last bin contains values that range from 95-100. I would like to shade in red the number of data points that have a value of 100 in this bin.

```
data<-c(78,100,90,100,96,100,100,82,95,99,100,97,79,99,100,77,79,100,95,100,100,100,82,77,82)
hist(data, xlab="Score",breaks=c(75,80,85,90,95,100),ylab = "Frequency", main = paste("Score Distribution"), cex.main = 1.55, cex.lab = 1, freq = TRUE)
```

Current Image

[image]
Desired Image

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you should be probably using bar plots rather than histograms. And you've tagged ggplot2 but you are just using base graphics in your example. Does it matter what's used?

Comment: I'm open to using a bar chart format so long as it looks like a histogram. I added ggplot2 since I know ggplot2 has more flexibility with formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `add=T`

```
data<-c(78,100,90,100,96,100,100,82,95,99,100,97,79,99,100,77,79,100,95,100,100,100,82,77,82)
hist(data, xlab="Score",breaks=c(75,80,85,90,95,100),ylab = "Frequency", main = paste("Score Distribution"), cex.main = 1.55, cex.lab = 1, freq = TRUE)

newdata <- data[data == 100]

hist(newdata, xlab="Score",breaks=c(75,80,85,90,95,100),ylab = "Frequency", main = paste("Score Distribution"), cex.main = 1.55, cex.lab = 1, freq = TRUE, col="red", add=T)
```